# using a string to reference an object in C#

Tags: c#, string, object, reference

```
    private void check_boxes(ref int which_series_a, string wh_bx)
    {
        // ******************** Checks to see if box is checked **********************
        if (wh_bx.Checked == true)
```

I have tried `this.` and `this.Controls` and nothing works.

Comment: is `wh_bx` an ID of a control? Any reason you can't pass the control instance itself?

Comment: Without knowing what sort of values the `wh_bx` contain, and how those values relate to control objects on your form, it's hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming wh_bx is the name of the checkbox.

```
 private void check_boxes(ref int which_series_a, string wh_bx)
 {   
  var myCtrl = this.Controls.Find(wh_bx, true) as CheckBox;
  if(myCtrl != null)
  {
     if(myCtrl.Checked){}
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you going to need `myCtrl` to be of type `CheckBox` before accessing the `Checked` property?